# How to fix mock_open differences in calls but not in end result

Tags: python, json, mocking

Using [mock_open](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#mock-open), I can capture the data from writes using the `with [...] as` construct. However, testing that what I have is correct is a little tricky.  For example, I can do this:

```
>>> from mock import mock_open
>>> m = mock_open()
>>> with patch('__main__.open', m, create=True):
...     with open('foo', 'w') as h:
...         h.write('some stuff')
...
>>> m.mock_calls
[call('foo', 'w'),
 call().__enter__(),
 call().write('some stuff'),
 call().__exit__(None, None, None)]
>>> m.assert_called_once_with('foo', 'w')
>>> handle = m()
>>> handle.write.assert_called_once_with('some stuff')
```

But I want to do compare what I think should have been written to what was.  In effect something like this:

```
>>> expected = 'some stuff'
>>> assert(expected == m.all_that_was_written)
```

The problem I am facing with `call` is that different versions of json (2.0.9 vs 1.9) seem to print things differently. No, I cannot just update to the latest json.

The actual error I am getting is this:

```
E           AssertionError: [call('Tool_000.json', 'w'),
                             call().__enter__(),
                             call().write('['),
                             call().write('\n  '),
                             call().write('"1.0.0"'),
                             call().write(', \n  '),
                             call().write('"2014-02-27 08:58:02"'),
                             call().write(', \n  '),
                             call().write('"ook"'),
                             call().write('\n'),
                             call().write(']'),
                             call().__exit__(None, None, None)] 
            !=
                            [call('Tool_000.json', 'w'),
                             call().__enter__(),
                             call().write('[\n  "1.0.0"'),
                             call().write(', \n  "2014-02-27 08:58:02"'),
                             call().write(', \n  "ook"'),
                             call().write('\n'),
                             call().write(']'),
                             call().__exit__(None, None, None)]
```

In effects, the calls are different but the end result is the same.

The code I am testing is fairly simple:

```
with open(get_new_file_name(), 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(lst, fp)
```

So, creating another method that passes the file pointer seems overkill.

Comment: Not answering your question, but how about accepting a file object in the code you are testing?  Then you could use `StringIO.StringIO` as a mock file object, and simply use the `getvalue()` method to retrieve everything that has been written.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: This just pushes the open upwards and makes the code more convoluted: You create a file name, make sure it's valid, then open the file, then pass it to a function that will write to it.  The open code is pretty simple -- question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch `open()` to return `StringIO` object and then check the contents.

```
with mock.patch('module_under_test.open', create=True) as mock_open:
    stream = io.StringIO()
    # patching to make getvalue() work after close() or __exit__()
    stream.close = mock.Mock(return_value=None)
    mock_open.return_value = stream

    module_under_test.do_something() # this calls open()

    contents = stream.getvalue()
    assert(contents == expected)
```

**Edit**: added patch for `stream.close` to avoid exception on `stream.getvalue()`.

Comment: won't work because do_something might close the stream, and getvalue call will raise a ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: @kakarukeys Thanks, I've totally missed that! We can patch `stream.close`, but it doesn't seem right for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

`mock_open` is not fully featured yet. It works well if you are mocking files to be read but it does not yet have enough features for testing written files. The question clearly shows this deficiency.

My solution is to not use `mock_open` if you are testing the written content. Here is the alternative:

```
import six
import mock
import unittest

class GenTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_open_mock(self):
        io = six.BytesIO()
        io_mock = mock.MagicMock(wraps=io)
        io_mock.__enter__.return_value = io_mock
        io_mock.close = mock.Mock() # optional
        with mock.patch.object(six.moves.builtins, 'open', create=True, return_value=io_mock):
            # test using with
            with open('foo', 'w') as h:
                expected = 'some stuff'
                h.write(expected)
            self.assertEquals(expected, io.getvalue())
            # test using file handle directly
            io.seek(0); io.truncate() # reset io
            expected = 'other stuff'
            open('bar', 'w').write(expected)
            self.assertEquals(expected, io.getvalue())
            # test getvalue after close
            io.seek(0); io.truncate() # reset io
            expected = 'closing stuff'
            f = open('baz', 'w')
            f.write(expected)
            f.close()
            self.assertEquals(expected, io.getvalue())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I will do, write a method that returns the complete string from all calls of the write method.

```
class FileIOTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """ For testing code involving file io operations """
    def setUp(self):
        """ patches the open function with a mock, to be undone after test. """
        self.mo = mock_open()

        patcher = patch("builtins.open", self.mo)
        patcher.start()
        self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)

    def get_written_string(self):
        return ''.join(c[0][0] for c in self.mo.return_value.write.call_args_list)
```

An example of how to use it

```
class TestWriteFile(FileIOTestCase):
    def test_write_file__csv(self):
        save.write_file("a,b\n1,2", "directory", "C6L")
        self.mo.assert_called_once_with(os.path.join("directory", "C6L.csv"), 'w')
        self.assertEqual(self.get_written_string(), "a,b\n1,2")
```

Comment: Note that this approach has a few drawbacks: `write()` doesn't return number of written bytes, no support for `writelines()`, `truncate()`, `seek()`, etc. That said, most cases don't use these anyway.